# Is it possible to play a flash video stored in php?

Tags: php, mysql, flash

Suppose I have some videos stored in a MySQL database.
How do I play those videos on demand using flash.

Comment: dreamweaver is IDE, it does not make or edit flash videos. your question subject is not suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP to serve content of any type. For flash, I assume you could use something like:

```
<?php
$video = get_video_contents_from_db();
header('Content-type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
die($video);
```

Where `get_video_contents_from_db()` is some function that returns the contents of the video you have stored in your database. You might also need to specify additional headers, such as Content-length, but that is the general idea.

Comment: I don't want my videos to be fetched from database. It's actually saved as path, and the videos are in a folder.